# Blog backend for non developers Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a very simple, backend visual representation of creating a blog post.  Since the blog writers are not developers, I need something that can make blog posting easy.  I know RedCloth is available but I'm looking for something more simple, but not a CMS since it infects my app and mutates it like no other.

Comment: Something like [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)?

Comment: What's a "backend visual representation of creating a blog post"?

Comment: pretty much buttons that can make bullets, indent, bold the text, insert image, etc.  RailsAdmin looks good, ill try that out. thanks!

Comment: ActiveAdmin is more popular, https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) gem.

Here is a free (very helpful) [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin) that goes through the configuration and features of the gem.

[ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) should have no problem suiting your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Comfy Blog project.

https://github.com/comfy/comfy-blog

ComfyBlog is an simple blog management engine for Rails 3.1 apps. It also integrates with ComfortableMexicanSofa CMS Engine.  The nice thing about this project is that it doesn't interfere with your existing controllers, and "it's just Rails".